# HTML validation using JavaScript getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following validation summary in my page:

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I intend to show this error list using JavaScript `document.body.getElementById("cpErrorMsgTag").innerHTML`

The code would look something like this:

```
function ChangePasswordErrormessage() { 
    document.body.getElementById("cpErrorMsgTag").innerHTML = @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
}
```

My code results in the following: **uncaught syntax error**.

How can I implement the above statement. The intention of the code is to flush the validation error in a specific place of a page (which is why I am using `document.body.getElementById("cpErrorMsgTag").innerHTML`)

Comment: Well, as the error implies, that's not valid Javascript. I don't recognise the syntax, but presumably you know what language it comes from (presumably one of the many that compiles to JS?)

Comment: `@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" }` - is not valid JavaScript

Comment: What is `@Html` ?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using C# with razor pages?  If so, can't you position the validation summary anywhere in the page without using Javascript just by writing it out within cpErrorMsgTag?  In any case, please confirm what your backend language is.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are right, I can position it in the page itself but there are other requirements which has to be implemented along with the above mentioned code in a java script. The language you specified is correct. the js is written in a .cshtml file. see the validation works perfectly when I put it in a html format (for example if i want to show the error in a modal-it works from the .cshtml file) but I need to do it in js to show it in the tag cpErrorMsgTag

Answer (score 0):

Are you using C #? Is there a way to validate Data Annotations forms.

Microsoft:
[Validation with the Data Annotation Validators (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs)

There is a post on the stack talking about how to use Data Annotations as well.

StackOverflow:
[MVC Data Annotations in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32532610/mvc-data-annotations-in-razor)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The function `ChangePasswordErrormessage` is a javascript function and the statement `@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })` is a C# Razor markup.

You cannot use a C# helper function such as @Html.ValidationSummary inside a javascript function. I don't think there is a way to clear out error messages shown by ValidationSummary using native javascript. The only way to do this would be to re-render the view with a valid model state.